# Use test.assert in casperjs

Tags: casperjs

For the casperjs, I have:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({    
    loadImages:false,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');

casper.then(function(){
    this.echo('step 1 is finished!^.^');
});
```

I want use `casper.test.assert('Step1 is finished');`

When I run the code, I cannot use `casperjs myjs.js` anymore, because the new version need to use `casperjs test yourjs.js`. But when I use the new one, still give me the error

> You can’t override the preconfigured casper instance in this test environment

So, what show I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly what it says. You cannot create a casper instance when you run `casper test myjs.js`. It will be injected. Just change

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({    
    loadImages:false,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});
```

to

```js
casper.options.loadImages = false;
casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel = 'debug';
```

and use casper inside of test blocks:

```js
casper.test.begin('some test name', function(test) {
    casper.start(url);
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assert(this.getTitle()!=''); // straight forward
    })
    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you,this is worked. But I want to use some other function like Faker.js, but I cannot use " var Faker = require('./Faker');" what should I do?